# USB scanners not coming through on LTSP clients

Tags: ltsp

Have 30 workstations all running nicely on LTSP, each running ubuntu.
Bought 5 Epson V33 scanners, which of course worked fine on local ubuntu installs.

When these clients are running through LTSP the scanners are not detected.

Can anyone lend a hand with this? or give any ideas?

USB flash drives, keyboards , mice etc all come through nicely .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more detailed procedure that worked for me.

If, after you connect and switch on your scanner, you get the following output from this command,

```
sudo scanimage -L

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

but this command finds your scanner,

```
sudo sane-find-scanner

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  ....
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x0133 [EPSON Scanner] ...
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
```

then you need to install Espon drivers.

Visit this page

```
http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/
```

and enter GT-1500 for the product name, and Linux for the Operating Sytstem.

Eventually, you will need to 
download these packages from two separate download pages

```
iscan-plugin-gt-1500_2.2.0-1_amd64.deb
iscan_2.30.1-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_amd64.deb
iscan-data_1.36.0-1_all.deb
```

Next, install the standard Ubuntu package xsltproc followed by the three pages you have just downloaded

```
sudo apt-get install xsltproc
sudo dpkg -i iscan*
```

Afterwards, when scanimage should give you the following output

```
scanimage -L

device `epkowa:interpreter:002:004' is a Epson GT-1500 flatbed scanner
```

At this point, I could scan using simple-scan.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem with an Epson GT-1500 and I've found a solution which works, although not the best solution.

I had to install special epson drivers for my scanner into my chroot area for the clients
(Refer: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX)

Downloaded my drivers, copied them into my chroot section and installed with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install xsltproc
sudo dpkg -i iscan*
```

Once I had that installed I had to rebuild my ltsp image, reboot the client, then once the client was up I had to replug the scanner in. Then I could start simple scan locally and it would work.

```
 ltsp-localapp simple-scan
```

Make sure you scanner is coming up on the client

```
 ltsp-localapp xterm
```

Then within xterm

```
sane-find-scanner
```

You should see your scanner in here.